# Do fermented foods from India like idli and dosa contain vitamin B12?

Tags: health, b12

Do fermented foods from India like idli and dosa contain vitamin B12? Can eating these foods prevent vitamin B12 deficiency in vegetarian people?

Answer (score 5):

According to [this article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4266598/) idli and dosa contain little or no B12 (<0.001 micrograms per portion); indeed, they state B12 deficiency is a problem in India due to the prevalence of Vegetarian diet.

[image: B12 Content in Foods]

While some fermented soy foods, algae, and mushrooms contain B12 (see, for example [this article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4042564/)), veg*ans are generally [advised to eat supplements](https://www.vegansociety.com/resources/nutrition-and-health/nutrients/vitamin-b12/what-every-vegan-should-know-about-vitamin-b12).

Comment: but a lacto vegetarian diet would be healthy as regards vitamin b12, right

Comment: @vidyarthi lacto vegetarian would have more b12 than vegan, but I would hesitate to say that you are healthy with respect to B12.  If you look at the article I linked, they studied Indians, some of whom were deficient in B12 despite eating milk. Indeed, they write in the abstract that "Milk and curd (yoghurt) intakes were unrelated to B12 status."

Comment: the study you linked measured the blood samples of 'normal' people. Actually, in India, particularly south india, 'normal' people consume very less dairy products. All they consume is mainly a little curd used as a side dish. The children are given only a little of milk based sweet drink like Bournvita, Complan etc., Milk is taken as a luxury in south india, and not as a proper food. This is the cause of deficiency in B vitamins, in my purview

Comment: I also read it on a general knowledge course book that all fermented foods contains vitamin B12. but your post is far better that that book for knowledge.